# Tracking tab events in jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

I currently have `tabs()` working on a page with 4 tabs.

I am trying to use event tracking to track tab clicks which works fine EXCEPT on initial page load.  I want the page to identify which tab is loaded on page load but it is not registering

My Code:

```
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ 
        //activate to pass the active tab on click to the hidden field
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#activeTab').val($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active'));
            trackEvent('DeptPerformance', 'Tabs', $("#tabs .ui-tabs-active").text());
        },
        disabled: [<?=($isGroup?0:'')?>],
        active: <?=($isGroup?1:0)?>
    });
```

I tried adding:

```
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            trackEvent('DeptPerformance', 'Tabs', $("#tabs .ui-tabs-active").text());
        },
```

But this does not track the event.

Is there another method or event I should be using to track the event once the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Further testing identified that the analytics code was not loaded when the tab is created - added a timeout to wait 1 second for analytics to catch up.

to fix:

```
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ 
        //activate to pass the active tab on click to the hidden field
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#activeTab').val($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active'));
            trackEvent('DeptPerformance', 'Tabs', $("#tabs .ui-tabs-active").text());
        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                 trackEvent('DeptPerformance', 'Tabs', $("#tabs .ui-tabs-active").text());
            }, 1000);
        },
        disabled: [<?=($isGroup?0:'')?>],
        active: <?=($isGroup?1:0)?>
    });
```

Comment: You could also try using `.ready()` if there is an element that loads for analytics. This could be used to fire a function once that element is ready.